# Gulp Watch Task not working

Tags: gulp

I was doing these basic tasks to watch my js files and then to watch my styl files. The js watch was working fine since I was following some tutorial. Then I was doing the `watch:styles` task. Firstly I tried to put it in the same watch as the JS (is that possible?) but since it wasn't working I did a separated task. Now my js watcher won't work at all. If I run browserify it works, it's just the watcher that doesn't.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var browserify = require('browserify');

var babelify = require('babelify');

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');


gulp.task('browserify', function () {

return browserify('./res/js/main.js')

    .transform(babelify, { presets:["es2015"] })

    .bundle()

    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./res/js'));

});



gulp.task('watch', function () {

gulp.watch('**/*.js', ['browserify']);

});

gulp.task('styles', function () {

     gulp.src('./res/css/main.styl')

    .pipe(stylus())

    .pipe(gulp.dest('res/css'));

});

gulp.task('watch:styles', function () {

    gulp.watch('**/*.styl', ['styles']);

 });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Simple and clear statements of problems are appreciated. State what you expect your code to do and what it actually does instead. "It doesn't work" is less than clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The gulp task wasn't converting the main.js file to the bundle.js file as requested. It was my mistake because it was working, it just takes 15~ seconds to start the task and i was trying to test it before the 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar issue, I recommend adding the dependent task to the `gulp.task` instead `gulp.watch`, it worked for me. But honestly I'm not sure this is the better solution.

`gulp.task('watch:styles', ['styles'],function () { gulp.watch('**/*.styl'); });`

Answer (score 0):

So, my bad, the task was working fine. The problem is it takes around 15 seconds(why?) to start, so everytime i tested it before the 15 seconds it wouldnt work.

As for watching both css and js files in the same task i fixed it this way.

```
    gulp.task('watch', function () {

       gulp.watch('**/*.js', ['browserify'])
       gulp.watch('**/*.styl', ['styles']);

   });
```